# Importing RSA keys in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I wanted to encrypt/decrypt/sign... and so on and I found this code:

```
public $pubkey = '...public key here...';
public $privkey = '...private key here...';

public function encrypt($data)
{
    if (openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->pubkey))
        $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
    else
        throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

    return $data;
}

public function decrypt($data)
{
    if (openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $decrypted, $this->privkey))
        $data = $decrypted;
    else
        $data = '';

    return $data;
}
```

The only problem is that I got a private.pem (or .key dosnt matter) format and the question:

**How should I import my private.pem file in this code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `openssl_pkey_get_public()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php

It decrypt the .pem format and extracts the keys necessary for the work.

Comment: public $pubkey = 'file://path/to/public/key-crt.pem'; This dosnt work I think because it only takes the data inside and not decrypt it but the  http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php does work edit your answer then I will accept it